# Career in applied mathematics after MS in abstract mathematics?

Tags: career-path, mathematics

For someone who is more interested in applied mathematics than abstract, which degree should one pursue in order to have a career in applied mathematics, considering he/she has pursued an MS in abstract mathematics?
Is it advisable, considering that the person does not know much of the basics of applied mathematics?

Comment: Just a note, but abstract mathematics can certainly be applied (or at least applicable). See, for instance, the work of Robert Ghrist on applied topology.

Comment: As @JW suggests, the labels "abstract" and "applied" are not now, and maybe never were, "opposites" or to be put in contrast. To answer your question meaningfully, you might tell what you _mean_ by "applied math", not to justify the label, but to explain what mathematics you are putting it on, so that people can respond to that. (Yes, there is a tradition that "applied math" means numerical or heuristic solution of PDE, but... much more math than that was and is applied, and solving PDEs has to count as pretty abstract, in the first place!)

Comment: http://www.brightknowledge.org/knowledge-bank/science-and-maths/spotlight-on-maths/applied-vs.-pure-mathematics .... such links made me ask this question here (i am sure to get clear answers here).

Comment: Surely, the two are not opposites but they do have differences. To be precise, I wish to consider the difference in content, as mentioned in http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pure-and-applied-mathematics

Comment: Perhaps it would help to edit your question to include the most relevant information from the links in your comments above.

Comment: That alleged difference in content, expressed in your link to quora, is a naive and simplistic opinion. Yes, it has appeal because it answers a question in simple (but false) terms. It is more relevant to say whether you'd aim to work in academe, or in industry. Whether you'd like to collaborate with scientists in non-math departments. Whether you want to be "part of a team", versus choosing your own projects.

Comment: You may also find it valuable to browse the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics' [career pages](http://www.siam.org/careers/).

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about doing an additional Master's degree after having already been awarded an MS in mathematics? Or are you wondering about undertaking a PhD with an applied focus after an MS without said focus?

Comment: One of my statistician friends told me that lots of Statistics chairs he knows were originally pure mathematicians and didn't have any training in stats.

Comment: @J W the latter option

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a Master's degree in mathematics, you should be capable of learning additional mathematics topics yourself. If you are interested in a particular field in which mathematics is applied, you can always spend some time becoming acquainted with that field and the mathematics involved. The Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (http://www.siam.org/) is one  resource to get an idea of what's out there. You might look for a smallish project to test the water and pick up some experience in mathematical modeling and, if relevant, computational mathematics. Years ago as a student, I did a summer project on modeling measles epidemics using difference equations. It was a valuable experience and taught me more than merely reading about mathematical modeling in a book or on a website.

You may also wish to bear in mind that seemingly pure mathematics can often end up being very applicable, so you may be able to have the best of both worlds. For instance, [Bernd Sturmfels](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/) has used algebraic geometry in statistics and computational biology and [Robert Ghrist](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/) has applied algebraic topology to signal processing and sensor networks.

Comment: Don't forget [Mumford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mumford)!